# is there any way to convert this ajax call into django api?

Tags: python, django, ajax

This is my login code which was build elrier in ajax call now i want to make API end points for this so i converted this all into class view although this is not correct but i need some help when i am checking this with postman i m getting error this is not post request.
i tried (self,request,args,krgws) but did not work

```
class LoginAPIView(APIView):
    def login(request):
        """
        dashboard login
        :param request:
        :return:
        """
        logger.info("inside login")
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_superuser:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('activity:index'))
        if request.is_ajax():
            username = request.POST.get('username', None)
            password = request.POST.get('password', None)
            if password is None or username is None:
                return JsonResponse({'status': 'failed'})
            msg = {}
            try:
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() and user is not None:
                    groups = Group.objects.all().values('name')
                    check_group = lambda user_group, groups : any(ug in groups for ug in user_group)
                    if (not user.groups or not check_group(user.groups.all().values("name"), groups)) and not user.is_superuser:
                        return JsonResponse({"redirect_url" : "/"})
                if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                        auth_login(request, user)
                        msg['status'] = 'ok'
                        user_activity = {"email": user.email,
                                        "first_name": user.first_name,
                                        "last_name": user.last_name,
                                        "activity": 'logged in'}
                        UserActivity.objects.create(**user_activity)
                    else:
                        msg['status'] = 'failed'
                else:
                    msg['status'] = 'failed'
            except:
                msg['status'] = 'failed'
            return JsonResponse(msg)
        else:
            raise Http404('page not found.')
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: where is code which uses ajax and POST method to call this function?